# skip password protected files with pypdf (only algorithm code 1 and 2 are supported)

Tags: python, encryption, pypdf, try-except

I am running the checkPdf function for a few different pdf links in a list.

```
def getResponse(url):
    try:
        response = requests.get(url)
    except:
        response = None
    return response

def getNumberOfPages(response):
    with BytesIO(response.content) as open_pdf_file:
        read_pdf = PdfFileReader(open_pdf_file)
        if read_pdf.isEncrypted:
            read_pdf.decrypt("")
        num_pages = read_pdf.getNumPages()
        return num_pages
    
def checkPDFs(pdfLinks):
    pdfDetails = {}
    for link in pdfLinks:
        pdfDetails[link] = {}
        response = getResponse(link)
        pdfDetails[link]["numberOfPages"] = getNumberOfPages(response)
        #pdfDetails[link]["creationDate"] = getDocumentInfo(response)
    print("PDF details", pdfDetails)
    return pdfDetails
```

It works for some but doesnt work for others and throws an error

```
<ipython-input-46-3213ac4b89ef> in checkPDFs(companyName, pdfLinks)
     29         pdfDetails[link] = {}
     30         response = getResponse(link)
---> 31         pdfDetails[link]["numberOfPages"] = getNumberOfPages(response)
     32         #pdfDetails[link]["creationDate"] = getDocumentInfo(response)
     33     print("PDF details", pdfDetails)

<ipython-input-46-3213ac4b89ef> in getNumberOfPages(response)
     10         read_pdf = PdfFileReader(open_pdf_file)
     11         if read_pdf.isEncrypted:
---> 12             read_pdf.decrypt("")
     13         num_pages = read_pdf.getNumPages()
     14         return num_pages

c:\users\nh\appdata\local\programs\python\python39\lib\site-packages\PyPDF2\pdf.py in decrypt(self, password)
   1985         self._override_encryption = True
   1986         try:
-> 1987             return self._decrypt(password)
   1988         finally:
   1989             self._override_encryption = False

c:\users\nh\appdata\local\programs\python\python39\lib\site-packages\PyPDF2\pdf.py in _decrypt(self, password)
   1994             raise NotImplementedError("only Standard PDF encryption handler is available")
   1995         if not (encrypt['/V'] in (1, 2)):
-> 1996             raise NotImplementedError("only algorithm code 1 and 2 are supported")
   1997         user_password, key = self._authenticateUserPassword(password)
   1998         if user_password:

NotImplementedError: only algorithm code 1 and 2 are supported
```

I have tried the decrypting within the getNumberOfPages function but it doesnt work. I do not know passwords. Is there any way I can get around it? Or else, is there any way I can skip the encrypted files in my code? So for example if I am unable to decrypt a file, I want to return a string "encrypted" instead of the error. How can I modify my script?

Answer (score 1):

You can simply catch the `NotImplementedError` in a try->except block. [w3schools article](https://www.w3schools.com/python/python_try_except.asp).

Replace the `if` that is throwing the error with the below code.

```py
        if read_pdf.isEncrypted:
            try:
                read_pdf.decrypt("")
            except NotImplementedError as e:
                print(e)
                return 'encrypted' # or whatever
```